# Android null pointer on setText()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I've got a method inside my activity which is calling setText(), but it's returning a nullpointerexception on the textView. Can anyone tell me why?

See below for the snippets:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playing);
```

...

```
    songArtistAlbumLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songArtistAlbumLabel);
```

...

```
static void displaySong(String currentArtist, String currentAlbum,
        String currentTitle, String totalDuration, Uri currentSongUri) {
    songArtistAlbumLabel.setText((currentArtist) + " - " + (currentAlbum));
        }
```

...

I need to keep the method displaySong as static, for various reasons, so I can't put the

```
 songArtistAlbumLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songArtistAlbumLabel);
```

Inside the method.. AFAIK. Also, the nullpointerexception occurs at the line

```
songArtistAlbumLabel.setText((currentArtist) + " - " + (currentAlbum));
```

Inside the method.

Any advice is much appreciated.

--Edit--

Full code:

```
package awesome.music.player;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MusicPlayer extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    public ImageButton play;
    public ImageButton next;
    public ImageButton previous;

    public static ImageView albumArt;

    static TextView songArtistAlbumLabel;
    static TextView songTitleLabel;
    static TextView currentDurationLabel;
    static TextView totalDurationLabel;

    static String serviceStatus;

    private SeekBar seekBar;

    private int seekMax;

    boolean mBroadcastIsRegistered;

    public static Utilities utils;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playing);

        play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        previous = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.previousButton);
        albumArt = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        songArtistAlbumLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songArtistAlbumLabel);

        play.setOnClickListener(playListener);
        next.setOnClickListener(nextListener);
        previous.setOnClickListener(previousListener);



        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_SEEKBAR);

        if (mBroadcastIsRegistered != true) {
            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                    MusicService.BROADCAST_ACTION));;

            mBroadcastIsRegistered = true;
        }

    }

    private OnClickListener playListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MusicService.playSong();

        }
    };

    private OnClickListener nextListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MusicService.playNext();
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener previousListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MusicService.playPrevious();
        }
    };

    public static final String BROADCAST_SEEKBAR = "awesome.music.player.sendseekbar";
    Intent intent;

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent serviceIntent) {
            updateUI(serviceIntent);
        }
    };

    static void displaySong(String currentArtist, String currentAlbum,
            String currentTitle, String totalDuration, Uri currentSongUri) {



        songArtistAlbumLabel.setText(currentArtist + " - " + currentAlbum);

        songTitleLabel.setText(currentTitle);

        totalDurationLabel.setText(totalDuration);

        albumArt.setImageURI(currentSongUri);

    }

    private void updateUI(Intent serviceIntent) {
        String counter = serviceIntent.getStringExtra("counter");
        String mediamax = serviceIntent.getStringExtra("mediamax");
        String strSongEnded = serviceIntent.getStringExtra("song_ended");
        int seekProgress = Integer.parseInt(counter);
        seekMax = Integer.parseInt(mediamax);
        Integer.parseInt(strSongEnded);
        seekBar.setMax(seekMax);
        seekBar.setProgress(seekProgress);
    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        if (fromUser) {
            int seekPos = seekBar.getProgress();
            intent.putExtra("seekpos", seekPos);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }

    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

--Edit 2--

Added xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="296dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_x="10dp"
        android:layout_y="446dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seek_handler" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="37dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_x="6dp"
        android:layout_y="397dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_tab_albums_white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songTitleLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="55dp"
        android:layout_y="395dp"
        android:text="Song Label"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songArtistAlbumLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="55dp"
        android:layout_y="417dp"
        android:text="Artist - Album Label"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currentDurationLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="10dp"
        android:layout_y="481dp"
        android:text="0:00" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalDurationLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="281dp"
        android:layout_y="477dp"
        android:text="3:30" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="41dp"
        android:layout_y="312dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/previousButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="132dp"
            android:layout_y="308dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_previous" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/playButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50sp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_pause" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_next" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="287dp"
        android:layout_height="272dp"
        android:layout_x="16dp"
        android:layout_y="13dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dummy_album_art"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Try like this, songArtistAlbumLabel.setText(currentArtist+ "_" + currentAlbum);

Comment: plz post full code , dont paste block ..

Comment: making `displaySong` static, while using `songArtistAlbumLabel.setText()` in it indicates serious flaws in design

Comment: songArtistAlbumLabel.setText("("+currentArtist+")"+ "_" + currentAlbum);

Comment: from where you calling displaySong() function ? out side this class?

Comment: also, you cannot put `songArtistAlbumLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songArtistAlbumLabel);` inside your static method, since `findViewById()` is not a static method.

Comment: Thanks guys.

@Aerrow - Thanks. This hasn't solved the problem though.

Comment: @PadmaKumar - Thanks. I'm not trying to call displaySong() from a service. What would you suggest I do instead of making it static?

Comment: @DheereshSingh - Please see the above full code. displaySong() is called from a service class.

Comment: @user1049280 - I've included the xml now. Thanks for having a look.

Comment: @CapDroid - I've included the full code now. Thanks

Comment: communicating with service using static function in is not good option .......use ServiceConnection in binder service if possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nullpointerexception` is not the main problem here. The problem lays in your design.

You make the `displaySong()` method static, I assume, to be able to call it from outside your activity. You use `TextView songArtistAlbumLabel` in it, so you have to make it static as well. But it's a major flaw in design, since static fields do not belong to the class instance, they belong to the class. `songArtistAlbumLabel`, however, should obviously belong to Activity instance. Here is a possible scenario - you call `displaySong()` method, while Activity was never launched, so `displaySong` is `null` and you get `npe`. Here is another possible scenario - you call `displaySong()` after Activity was destroyed and `songArtistAlbumLabel` is nowhere on the screen, but you are still trying to set a label for it.

There is a dirty hack - you can store reference to an instance of Activity in another static field with a public getter method (kinda like singleton), and refer to it in your static method to `findViewById()`. But this does not make things any better.

Solution would be to use [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to pass messages to activity from the outside and check for them in `onCreate()` via `getIntent()` method and listening to them in [onNewIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) method of your activity

**EDIT** if you are only going to call it from the service, check `The Music Player` section in [The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development](http://commonsware.com/Android/)

Comment: I've update the code to reflect everything that is happening within the activity. Is there a 'clean' solution, I didn't think what I was doing would be so complicated.. I'm just trying to set an activity's textView using variables determined in an activity.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you call `displaySong()` after setting `songArtistAlbumLabel`, the most likely explanation is that `R.id.songArtistAlbumLabel` doesn't match any id in your layout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Darshan. R.id.songArtistAlbumLabel is in the xml though.